# How to detect JSP is loading in a PORTLET or a BROWSER with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay, portlet

I am trying to write a JSP on based on certain criteria. Where I need to determine whether its loading in a Portlet or an actual Browser.

Here I am using Liferay Portlets, where Liferay versions are changing by other teams.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, you typically won't need to determine if you're running in a portlet or standalone application. What you need is URLs to interact with. And you should let the developers of the application in question provide the proper URL to contact - either that'll be a portlet URL, or a servlet URL. And/or maybe some mapping for field names or namespaces - but that's it.

Condense all of the differences between the two environments so much that they're just some data - then you can have the data being generated before the script code is delivered to your browser.